# Since when do divs support the `onchange` event, and is it a bug?

Tags: javascript, html

I've just accidentally bound a `div` that contained a radio button to an `onchange` event, instead of the actual radio button that was in it, and found that the event still fired. I have now ran the Fiddle below, in Firefox and a Webkit browser, and they both worked.

As I've never seen or heard mention of this before, I am now wondering if this is intended, is it new, and is it okay to use it in production and expect it to work in all (or older) browsers? Neither [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) or [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onchange.asp) mention non-input elements for the `onchange` event.

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/4cjdy9do/

Comment: Thats because of event bubbling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`div` doesn't have its *own* `change` event, but `change` *bubbles*. (And that's not new.) From [the MDN page you linked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change):

> Bubbles: Yes

So you'll see `change` on any element (not just `div`) containing an `input` or `select`, provided the event isn't prevented from bubbling by `stopPropagation`.

For instance, you can watch for all (non-stopped) `change` events on `document`, because the bubble there from their original target elements:

```js
document.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  console.log("Got change, new value: " + e.target.value);
});
```

```html
<div>
  <label>
    One:
    <input type="text">
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    Two:
    <input type="text">
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    Three:
    <select>
      <option>ay</option>
      <option>bee</option>
      <option>see</option>
    </select>
  </label>
</div>
```